# Is Follow-up record created within 7 days?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following sample data, and what I'm trying to determine is show the ClientIDs where a Schedule record has a DateCompleted value, but has not had a Complete Type record created within 7 days.

Based off the below data, ClientID 1 only would be returned.

```
Create Table #temp
(
    ClientID int,
    Type varchar(50),
    DateCreated datetime,
    DateCompleted datetime
)

insert into #temp
(
    ClientID,
    Type,
    DateCreated,
    DateCompleted
)
select
    1,
    'Schedule',
    '01 Oct 2020',
    '20 Oct 2020'
union all
select
    2,
    'Schedule',
    '15 Oct 2020',
    '01 Nov 2020'
union all
select
    4,
    'Schedule',
    '15 Oct 2020',
    '01 Nov 2020'
union all
select
    4,
    'Complete',
    '02 Nov 2020',
    '02 Nov 2020'
union all
select
    5,
    'Schedule',
    '15 Sep 2020',
    '25 Sep 2020'
union all
select
    5,
    'Complete',
    '02 Oct 2020',
    '02 Oct 2020'
union all
select
    5,
    'Schedule',
    '15 Oct 2020',
    NULL
```

[image]

Comment: Given your data I am not sure how just ClientID 1 would be the only one returned.  ClientID 2 does not have a Complete record, ClientID 4 has more than 7 days between  Scheduled and Complete as does ClientID 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, ids `1` and `1` should both be returned.

The following returns all clients with a valid schedule complete time, but no "completed" record within 7 days:

```
select distinct t.clientId
from temp t
where t.type = 'Schedule' and
      t.datecompleted is not null and
      not exists (select 1
                  from temp t2
                  where t2.clientid = t.clientid and
                        t2.type = 'Complete' and
                        datediff(day, t.datecompleted, t2.datecompleted) <= 7
                 );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fb14c9edb345ed0d958e62c4ffa41516) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, you need a comparison to the current date:

```
select distinct t.clientId
from temp t
where t.type = 'Schedule' and
      t.datecompleted < dateadd(day, -7, getdate()) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from temp t2
                  where t2.clientid = t.clientid and
                        t2.type = 'Complete' and
                        datediff(day, t.datecompleted, t2.datecompleted) <= 7
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that's on the right track, but ID  2 shouldn't show as it the Schedule record was Completed on 1st Nov and as it's 3rd Nov, 7 days haven't passed yet. Any ideas?

Comment: @Philip . . . That explains why "2" is not included.  Fixing that is easy.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand that you can use `DATEDIFF()` function with `day` as the first argument

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, DateCreated, DateCompleted ) <= 7 THEN
                 'Yes'
            ELSE
                 'No'
             END AS "Completed IN One Week"
  FROM #temp
```

**Update :** depending on the comment; *need to see whether there is an associated "Complete" row* use this query :

```
SELECT ClientID
  FROM #temp
 GROUP BY ClientID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Type='Complete' THEN 1 END)>0
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9f997ae19da808ef8826abf7ac67663e)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Barbaros, that's wrong because it needs to see whether there is an associated "Complete" row.

Comment: Hi @Philip , edit the question with comprehensible details added, please.

Answer (score 0):

Phillip, I hope this will help you.

`Select * from #temp where datecompleted is not null and type='Schedule' and datediff(d,datecompleted,getdate())>7 and clientid not in (select distinct Clientid from #temp where  type='Complete')`